# Desktop icon missing from Windows7 Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, shortcuts

Suddenly the desktop icon from my Windows 7 taskbar disappeared. Can someone tell me how can I restore the default icons of taskbar? Thanks.

Comment: Is your desktop properly aligned on the monitor so that the edge (where the Show Desktop button is, beside the clock) aren't hanging out-of-view?  Have you tried a System Restore to a point before it disappeared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To re-create the Show desktop icon yourself, follow these steps:

(1) Click Start, click Run, type notepad in the Open box, and then click OK.

(2) Carefully copy and then paste the following text into the Notepad window:

```
[Shell] 
Command=2 
IconFile=explorer.exe,3
[Taskbar]
Command=ToggleDesktop
```

(3) On the File menu, click Save As, and then save the file to your desktop as "Show desktop.scf". The Show desktop icon is created on your desktop.

(4) Click and then drag the Show desktop icon to your Quick Launch toolbar.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190355#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways

P.S. If you do not have a Quick Launch bar, see: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/add-the-quick-launch-bar-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen a Desktop icon in Windows 7, just this subtle button named "Show Desktop".  Does that suit what you want?

[image: Show Desktop]

Comment: As this button is exactly on the opposite side of screen as the quick launch usually is (next to Start button) it is not very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried right-clicking desktop > View > Show desktop icon